# How to dump mysql table structure without data with a SQL query?

Tags: database, mysql

I need to export a mysql table, but it has like 5gb of entries, so I only want the structure. I am trying to do it from a simple php doing a sql query, how can I do that?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can use [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html) for this.

> Shows the CREATE TABLE statement that
>   creates the given table. The statement
>   requires the SELECT privilege for the
>   table. As of MySQL 5.0.1, this
>   statement also works with views.

E.g.:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE MyTablename
```

Answer (score 88):

I'm not a MySQL expert by any means but the following [site](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mysql/dump-just-the-table-structure-to-a-file-in-mysql/) suggests using the `-d` or `--no-data` option of mysqldump:

```
mysqldump -d -h localhost -u root -pmypassword databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I was looking for the answer to the original question, but I find this answer very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

if u have "MySQL Workbench" v6.0

1) click on any table of the database.

2) Right-click and select "Tables Maintenance"

3) Under "Tables" tab, highlight the tables u want to export, right-click and select "Send to SQL Editor">"Create Schema"

Answer (score 2):

It is already answered in the link below:
[MySql export schema without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data)

Use the command below to take the structure or schema dump.

```
mysqldump -u root -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql
```