# Export schema without data

Tags: sql, mysql, database, database-schema, dump

I'm using a MySql database with a Java program, now I want to give the program to somebody else.

How to export the MySQL database structure without the data in it, just the structure?

Answer (score 1273, accepted):

You can do with the `--no-data` option with mysqldump command

```sh
mysqldump -h yourhostnameorIP -u root -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql
```

Comment: IMHO, `mysqldump` is the best answer. MySQL Administrator is abandoned and MySQL Workbench is still quite buggy.

Comment: Also consider using the `--single-transaction` option if you don't want or can't do table locks.

Comment: -d is --no-data for short.

Comment: Is it also possible to export the database without data except a few tables? Or is it easier to do this in multiple exports?

Comment: Also consider adding --routines if you're database has stored procedures/functions

Comment: By default, this does not include the `CREATE DATABASE` command. To include, replace `dbname` with `--databases dbname` (shorthand: `-B dbname`).  Then to import on another server, use `mysql -u root -p < schema.sql`

Comment: To avoid having the character set of your shell interfere with encoding, -r schema.sql is preferred over > schema.sql.  Also a good idea to specify the character set explicitly with --default-character-set=utf8 (or whatever).  You'll still want to check the set names at the top of the dump file.  I've been caught in MySQL charset encoding hell before...

Comment: you may want to use `--single-transaction` to avoid issues with LOCK Tables while executing the dump.

Comment: Summing all the options in the comments, the complete command is: `mysqldump -u root -p --single-transaction -d -R -B -r schema_structure_backup.sql schema_name`

Answer (score 133):

Yes, you can use `mysqldump` with the `--no-data` option:

```
mysqldump -u user -h localhost --no-data -p database > database.sql
```

Comment: I'm surprised this is not the accepted answer despite being posted ten seconds earlier and being more complete if not identical to the accepted answer.

Comment: @zypA13510, apparently ten seconds can be a difference of 749 upvotes.

Answer (score 25):

you can also extract an individual table with the `--no-data` option

```
mysqldump -u user -h localhost --no-data -p database tablename > table.sql
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the -d option with mysqldump command

```
mysqldump -u root -p -d databasename > database.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

Dumping without using output.

```
mysqldump --no-data <database name> --result-file=schema.sql
```

Answer (score 8):

Beware though that --no-data option will not include the view definition. So if yo had a view like following

```
create view v1 
 select `a`.`id` AS `id`,
 `a`.`created_date` AS `created_date` 
from t1;
```

with --no-data option, view definition will get changed to following

```
create view v1
 select 1 AS `id`, 1 AS `created_date`
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using IntelliJ you can enable the Database view (View -> Tools Window -> Database)

Inside that view connect to your database. Then you can rightclick the database and select "Copy DDL". Other IDEs may offer a similar function.

[image: IntelliJ DDL]

Comment: I gave it a try, it doesnt contain any triggers (and god knows what else not)

Comment: I used datagrip to generate DDL, and it somewhat didn't copy the default null and my database schema is inconsistent now :3

Answer (score 4):

You Can Use MYSQL Administrator Tool its free
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

you'll find many options to export ur MYSQL DataBase

Answer (score 4):

If you want to dump all tables from all databases and with no data (only database and table structures) you may use:

```
mysqldump -P port -h hostname_or_ip -u username -p --no-data --all-databases > db_backup.sql
```

This will produce a .sql file that you can load onto a mysql server to create a fresh database. 
Use cases for this are not many in a production environment, but I do this on a weekly basis to reset servers which are linked to demo websites, so whatever the users do during the week, on sunday nights everything rolls back to "new" :)

Answer (score 3):

Add the --routines and --events options to also include stored routine and event definitions

```
mysqldump -u <user> -p --no-data --routines --events test > dump-defs.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take using the following method

```
mysqldump -d <database name> > <filename.sql> // -d : without data
```

Comment: This answer adds nothing that other answer haven't already said.

Answer (score 1):

shell> mysqldump --no-data --routines --events test > dump-defs.sql

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You could make a great answer out of this if you give a little more information and constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Using mysql-backup4j its quite easy to backup any database with few lines of code.this will generate the sql dump for database that can later be use to restore database easily.

maven dependency required for this is :

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smattme</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-backup4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here goes the implementation in java..you can play with the cool parameter sets

```
/**
 * Creator : Tanvir Chowdhury
 * Date    : 2021-11-15
 */
public class BackupDatabase {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DB_NAME, "hcs_test_db");
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DB_USERNAME, "root");
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DB_PASSWORD, "root");
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DELETE_EXISTING_DATA, "true");
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.DROP_TABLES, "true");
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.ADD_IF_NOT_EXISTS, "true");
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.JDBC_DRIVER_NAME, "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hcs_test_db");

        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.TEMP_DIR, new File("/Users/tanvir/Desktop/backups/backup.sql").toString());
        properties.setProperty(MysqlExportService.PRESERVE_GENERATED_ZIP, "true");

        MysqlExportService mysqlExportService = new MysqlExportService(properties);
        mysqlExportService.export();

    }
}
```

if required you can also use the mail sending options quite easily to send the backup file to any email address.

Or You can do with the --no-data option with mysqldump command.If you want to do this from java then pass this command to runtime exec() method as param.

```
mysqldump -u root -h localhost --no-data -proot hcs_db_one?useSSL=false > db_one_dump.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can export only the schema of the tables of `apple` database to `backup.sql` with [-d(--no-data)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data) as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484667/export-mysql-dump-from-command-line/77363989#77363989) explains how to export both the schema and data of the tables of a database:

```
mysqldump -u john -p -d apple > backup.sql
```

Or:

```
mysqldump -u john -p --no-data apple > backup.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an individual table's creation script:
 - select all the table (with shift key)
 - just right click on the table name and click Copy to Clipboard > Create Statement.

Comment: you might want to update your answer with as to what program you are doing that in, for example MS SQL Server Mgmt. Studio or Oracle SQL Developer... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

From phpmyadmin you can do the following:

1. Export
2. Export method: Custom - display all possible options
3. Format-specific options: structure **NOT** structure and data

To export the entire database:

[image]