# How to get Database script for Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have Mysql database. I want to take only the skeleton of my database i.e.I want only the scripts to create Database and  tables. Not the entire database back up which comes with database structure and data.

Please Help me. I Use Mysql 5.0

Answer (score 3):

```
mysqldump --all-databases --no-data
```

Comment: +1 for --all-databases option.

Answer (score 0):

From [MySql export schema without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data):

> You can do with the `--no-data` option with `mysqldump` command
>
> ```
> mysqldump -u root -p --no-data dbname > schema.sql
> ```

[Jim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196869/jim) helpfully contributes:

> consider using the `--single-transaction` option if you don't want or can't do table locks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my summary about mysql dumping commands, hope to help you

backup the entire database

> mysqldump -uroot -p db_name > /home/bob/my.sql

backup single table

> mysqldump -uroot -p db_name table_name > /home/bob/table.sql

backup only database structure,

> mysqldump -uroot -p db_name -d > /home/bob/structure.sql

backup only database data

> mysqldump -uroot -p db_name -t > /home/bob/data.sql

**How to execute the exported sql file?** See the following

> mysql -uroot -p db_name < /home/bob/my.sql

another way,
Log into mysql, then

> mysql> use db_name;
>
> mysql> source /home/bob/my.sql;