# Dump MySQL tables with more than one row and no data

Tags: mysql, dump, mariadb

I have a mysql database with more than 300 tables. 100 tables have no data (0 rows). I want to create a dump (script file) with all the create tables statements of tables that have 1 or more rows and also dont include the data (without inserts)

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql export schema without data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data)

Comment: No, it is no duplicated, becausethe important (dificult) part is that I want the tables that have 1 or more rows. I need dump with some statement like this: BACKUP THE TABLES THAT ARE IN select * from information_schema.tables where TABLE_SCHEMA =  'name' and table_rows > 0;