# How to export database from mysqlworkbench to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench

I designed a schema in Mysql Workbench, I want to get a script from Mysql Workbench and use it in sql server

Comment: please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql export schema without data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data)

Comment: You can follow this link : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html. It might help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could transfer the database from mysql workbench to sql server using database converter which was very helpful.
I used https://www.spectralcore.com/fullconvert/ to do the conversion