# PySpark SQL: export schema structure

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using PySpark and for one of the datasets I need to export the schema of a dataframe. Similar to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175473/mysql-export-schema-without-data) but a pyspark version of the same.

Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: @user9613318, I want the output in the same way that mysql workbench would give. The linked answer would give me a json/dict

Comment: @ClockSlave can you show an example of the output you'd like? I don't know what output mysql workbench would give.